# Mixing DB configuration from file with Fluent NHibernate mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I stumbled upon the following problem: I wanted to configure the DB from config file but the mappings fluently (love it!) The configuration code looks like this:

```
var cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.Configure();
var fluentCfg = Fluently.Configure(cfg)
                        .Mappings(
                            m => m
                               .FluentMapping
                               .AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly));
```

However the config file has a property:

```
<property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">
  NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, 
  NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu
</property>
```

and after the cfg.Configure(); all looks good the configuration points to the LinFu bytecode provider BUT after the third line I see the configuration changed to using Castle. I looked in the Fluent's code and I might be wrong but it looks like they are overriding this property in PersistenceConfiguration.cs(line 50) in the constructor of PersistenceConfiguration:

```
values[ProxyFactoryFactoryClassKey] =  DefaultProxyFactoryFactoryClassName;
```

Does Fluent require Castle? Or may be I am doing something wrong or maybe this is just a bug?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but it might help you out. You can expose the configuration and make any changes that you need to, in code.

```
var cfg = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("ConnectionStringName")).ShowSql())
                .Mappings(m =>
                {
                    m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MapMarker>();
                    m.FluentMappings.Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<ConventionMarker>();
                })
                .ExposeConfiguration(x => x.SetProperty("proxyfactory.factory_class", "NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu"));
```

Comment: Sure, but the idea was to configure the DB from a config file (so that I can change conn.strings, db-s, etc. during deployment) and leave the mappings to fluent (to have a nice strongly typed, compile-time verifiable mappings).

Answer (score 0):

There's a `ProxyFactoryFactory` method chained off `Configure`.

```
Fluently.Configure()
  .ProxyFactoryFactory(name);
```

If you're not on 1.2, I believe it's under the `Database` call (see RexM's answer).